# Show result based of closest date to an crieteria

Tags: sql, closest

on/off  datetime

```
1   2016-05-02 06:04:08.000
0   2016-05-02 06:08:42.000
1   2016-05-02 06:11:54.000
1   2016-05-02 06:13:41.000
1   2016-05-02 06:14:07.000
1   2016-05-02 06:14:28.000
1   2016-05-02 06:14:50.000
1   2016-05-02 06:15:59.000
1   2016-05-02 06:16:26.000
1   2016-05-02 06:24:23.000
0   2016-05-02 07:46:32.000
1   2016-05-02 10:14:06.000
```

I have a problem with sorting out.

I want to show the datetime with the on/off.
But I only want the closest on/off = 1 before the 
on/off = 0.

DESIRED RESULT:

```
on/off  datetime
1   2016-05-02 06:04:08.000
0   2016-05-02 06:08:42.000
1   2016-05-02 06:24:23.000
0   2016-05-02 07:46:32.000
1   2016-05-02 10:14:06.000
```

Extra: if there is no 0 at the end it should give the `getdate()`.

---

NEXT STEP

Thanks alot
Found that the next step i needed to do

Starting    Ending
2016-05-02 06:04:14.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 06:08:31.000
2016-05-02 06:27:27.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 06:46:39.000
2016-05-02 06:47:10.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 06:51:31.000
2016-05-02 06:54:30.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 07:08:51.000
2016-05-02 07:10:21.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 07:12:31.000
2016-05-02 07:18:32.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 07:28:13.000
2016-05-02 07:29:02.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 07:33:00.000
2016-05-02 07:44:35.000 NULL
NULL    2016-05-02 07:45:47.000

I know i do this with a group if i have a reference but now i just have the 0 and 1

DESIRED RESULT

Starting    Ending
2016-05-02 06:04:14.000 2016-05-02 06:08:31.000
2016-05-02 06:27:27.000 2016-05-02 06:46:39.000
2016-05-02 06:47:10.000 2016-05-02 06:51:31.000
2016-05-02 06:54:30.000 2016-05-02 07:08:51.000
2016-05-02 07:10:21.000 2016-05-02 07:12:31.000
2016-05-02 07:18:32.000 2016-05-02 07:28:13.000
2016-05-02 07:29:02.000 2016-05-02 07:33:00.000
2016-05-02 07:44:35.000 2016-05-02 07:45:47.000

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time. For example `getdate()` is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ThisRow.*
from
( SELECT row_number() over (order by Date_Time) as RowNr
      ,[OnOff]
      ,[Date_Time]  FROM [VH_Stam].[dbo].[Values]
   )  ThisRow 
  left outer join
  ( SELECT row_number() over (order by Date_Time) as RowNr
      ,[OnOff]
      ,[Date_Time] FROM [VH_Stam].[dbo].[Values]
   )  PreviousRow on
  ThisRow.RowNr = PreviousRow.RowNr +1
Where ThisRow.RowNr = 1 or
PreviousRow.OnOff <> ThisRow.OnOff
```

Row number 1 is always selected, as this is always different from the non-existent row-number 0. And else only the rows which differ from the previous is selected.

Comment: Thanks alot
i edited the questian now.
Can you see if the next step is possible without a referense to group with